# Can you disable tabs in Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

Can you disable tabs in Bootstrap 2.0 like you can disable buttons?

Answer (score 200, accepted):

You could remove the `data-toggle="tab"` attribute from the tab as it's hooked up using live/delegate events

Comment: Thanks worked a treat, also added css "cursor:no-drop;" for cursor so use knows why they can't click it

Comment: cursor: not-allowed; is more appropriate in this case. Unless you are actually drag-and-dropping.

Comment: This helped me, thank you. To re-activate the tab just add the data-toggle attribute back to the <a> tag, child of the <li> of interest: `$('#my-tab-li-element').children('a').attr('data-toggle', 'tab');`

Comment: Or add a disabled class to the li

Comment: + Adding a `disabled` css-class to the `li`

Comment: You need to use both suggestions above: Add "disabled" class to <li> AND Remove data-toogle or href attribute from tab

Comment: I simply added this CSS and now `class="disabled"` works as expected `.nav.nav-tabs > li.disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
    a {
        color: silver;
    }
}`

Comment: The border of the currently active tab gets still removed with this solution, when I click on a disabled tab.

Comment: @effe super answer. Best solutions. It disables the click and allows us to navigate through next previous buttons. Where as the above solutions disables all the options to navigate.

Answer (score 51):

As of 2.1, from bootstrap documentation at http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navs, you can.

> Disabled state
>
> For any nav component (tabs, pills, or list), add .disabled for gray
>   links and no hover effects. Links will remain clickable, however,
>   unless you remove the href attribute. Alternatively, you could
>   implement custom JavaScript to prevent those clicks.

See https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/2764 for the feature add discussion.

Comment: this is one of the main functionalities and it boggles me it is not yet implemented

Comment: It is implemented in v3

Comment: Yes but links are still clickable.

Comment: Exactly, the viable solution so far is to remove the data-toggle attribute.

Answer (score 37):

I added the following Javascript to prevent clicks on disabled links:

```
$(".nav-tabs a[data-toggle=tab]").on("click", function(e) {
  if ($(this).hasClass("disabled")) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: I think a combination of this and @hotzu's response should be the answer.  You should add the `disabled` class to the `li` element and then add the javascript you specified except the condition you'd be checking against would be: `if ($(this).parent().hasClass('disabled')) {..}`.

Comment: @im1dermike I don't see why I would be doing this?

Comment: Old question, but it's what I found so I'm adding this. You would do that check because the `li` is what changes the visuals for the user and is consequently what should have the `disabled` class.

Answer (score 27):

i think the best solution is disabling with css.
You define a new class and you turn off the mouse events on it:

```
.disabledTab{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

And then you assign this class to the desired li element:

```
<li class="disabled disabledTab"><a href="#"> .... </a></li>
```

You can add/remove the class with jQuery also. For example, to disable all tabs:

```
$("ul.nav li").removeClass('active').addClass('disabledTab');
```

Here is an example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LJnn7/1/)

Comment: i would strongly recommend against that. since a css only solution leaves the tabs clickable. in case there are other events listening for those clicks, they will be executed, which is not the desired result. (i guess?)

Comment: In my case, this did the trick. I built a form consisting of multiple tabs. Going to the next tab is done via a button, which triggers a click-event on the tab to go to. So disabling clicks completely is not an option for me, but removing pointer events from the tabs was just what I needed.

Answer (score 20):

### No Need Any Jquery, Just One Line CSS

```
.nav-tabs li.disabled a {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: I had to do this on li.disabled (not li.disabled a)

Answer (score 11):

Also, I'm using following solution:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('click', function(){
  if ($(this).parent('li').hasClass('disabled')) {
    return false;
  };
});
```

Now you just adding class 'disabled' to the parent li and tab doesn't work and become gray.

Answer (score 6):

Old question but it kind of pointed me in the right direction. The method I went for was to add the disabled class to the li and then added the following code to my Javascript file.

```
$('.nav-tabs li.disabled > a[data-toggle=tab]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

This will disable any link where the li has a class of disabled. Kind of similar to totas's answer but it won't run the if every time a user clicks any tab link and it doesn't use return false.

Hopefully it'll be useful to someone!

Comment: good! but need e.preventDefault() before e.stopImmediatePropagation()

Answer (score 6):

For my use, the best solution was a mix of some of the answers here, which are :

- Adding the `disabled` class to the li I want to disable
- Add this piece of JS :

```js
$(".nav .disabled>a").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

- You can even remove the data-toggle="tab" attribute if you want Bootstrap to not interfer at all with your code.

****NOTE**:** The JS code here is important, even if you remove the data-toggle because otherwise, it will update your URL by adding the `#your-id` value to it, which is not recommended because your tab is disabled, thus should not be accessed.

Answer (score 5):

With ***only css***, you can define two css classes.

```
<style type="text/css">
    /* Over the pointer-events:none, set the cursor to not-allowed.
    On this way you will have a more user friendly cursor. */
    .disabledTab {
        cursor: not-allowed;
    }
    /* Clicks are not permitted and change the opacity. */
    li.disabledTab > a[data-toggle="tab"] {
        pointer-events: none;
        filter: alpha(opacity=65);
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
        opacity: .65;
    }
</style>
```

This is an html template. The only thing needed is to set the class to your preferred list item.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs tab-header">
    <li>
        <a href="#tab-info" data-toggle="tab">Info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="disabledTab">
        <a href="#tab-date" data-toggle="tab">Date</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#tab-photo" data-toggle="tab">Photo</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab-info">Info</div>
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab-date">Date</div>
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab-photo">Photo</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Suppose, this is your TAB and you want to disable it

```
<li class="" id="groups"><a data-toggle="tab" class="navuserli" href="#groups" aria-expanded="false">Groups</a></li>
```

So you can also disable this tab by adding dynamic css

```
$('#groups').css('pointer-events', 'none')
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to James's answer:

If you need to disable the link use

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').addClass('disabled');
```

If you need to prevent a disabled link from loading the tab

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').click(function(e){

            if($this.hasClass("disabled")){

                e.preventDefault();

                e.stopPropagation();

                e.stopImmediatePropagation();

                return false;

            }
}
```

If you need to unable the link

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').removeClass('disabled');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can disable a tab in bootstrap 4 by adding class `disabled` to the child of nav-item as follows

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" data-toggle="tab" href="#messages7" role="tab" aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="icofont icofont-ui-message"></i>Home</a>
    <div class="slide"></div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all suggested answers, but finally i made it work like this

```
if (false) //your condition
{
    $("a[data-toggle='tab'").prop('disabled', true);
    $("a[data-toggle='tab'").each(function () {
        $(this).prop('data-href', $(this).attr('href')); // hold you original href
        $(this).attr('href', '#'); // clear href
    });                
    $("a[data-toggle='tab'").addClass('disabled-link');
}
else
{
    $("a[data-toggle='tab'").prop('disabled', false);
    $("a[data-toggle='tab'").each(function () {
        $(this).attr('href', $(this).prop('data-href')); // restore original href
    });
    $("a[data-toggle='tab'").removeClass('disabled-link');
}
// if you want to show extra messages that the tab is disabled for a reason
$("a[data-toggle='tab'").click(function(){
   alert('Tab is disabled for a reason');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers work for me.  Remove `data-toggle="tab"` from the `a` prevents the tab from activating, but it also adds the `#tabId` hash to the URL. That is unacceptable to me.  What is also unacceptable is using javascript.

What does work is added the `disabled` class to the `li` and removing the `href` attribute of its containing `a`.

Comment: Now that I read down further, this is also basically the same exact answer as the one from @Scott Stafford, who answered it 2 years earlier...

Answer (score 0):

my tabs were in panels, so i added a class='disabled' to the tabs anchor

in javascript i added:

```
$(selector + ' a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')){
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
})
```

and for presentation in less i added:

```
.panel-heading{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    ul.nav-tabs{
        display:table-cell;
        vertical-align:bottom;
        a.disabled{
            .text-muted;
            cursor:default;
            &:hover{
                background-color:transparent;
                border:none;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most easy and clean solution to avoid this is adding  `onclick="return false;"` to `a` tag.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#home" onclick="return false;">Home</a>
    </li>    
    <li>
        <a href="#ApprovalDetails" onclick="return false;">Approval Details</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

- Adding `"cursor:no-drop;"` just makes cursor look disabled, but is **clickable**, Url gets appending with href target for ex `page.apsx#Home`
- No need of adding `"disabled"` class to `<li>` AND removing `href`

Answer (score -1):

Here's my attempt. To disable a tab:

1. Add "disabled" class to tab's LI;
2. Remove 'data-toggle' attribute from LI > A;
3. Suppress 'click' event on LI > A.

Code:

```
var toggleTabs = function(state) {
    disabledTabs = ['#tab2', '#tab3'];
    $.each(disabledTabs, $.proxy(function(idx, tabSelector) {
        tab = $(tabSelector);
        if (tab.length) {
            if (state) {
                // Enable tab click.
                $(tab).toggleClass('disabled', false);
                $('a', tab).attr('data-toggle', 'tab').off('click');
            } else {
                // Disable tab click.
                $(tab).toggleClass('disabled', true);
                $('a', tab).removeAttr('data-toggle').on('click', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            }
        }
    }, this));
};

toggleTabs.call(myTabContainer, true);
```