# Disabling Tabs in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-events

I am trying to disable the tabs in bootstrap. I have been researching and I have not yet found a solution.

I have tried this: [Can you disable tabs in Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237314/can-you-disable-tabs-in-bootstrap)
It has lead me to the bootstrap issues... I also tried `$('.disabled').removeData('toggle');`

I looked here.. https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/2764
Solution Attempted:
- Returning false

[jQuery disable a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970388/jquery-disable-a-link)
Solution Attempted:
- `event.defaultPrevented();`

And yet I have not come up with an answer. So far my problem is that the tab will disable, by returning false. However, when the tab is active and can be clicked it will not transition to the other tab like it should.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/de8QK/

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#store-tab').attr('class', 'disabled');
$('#bank-tab').attr('class', 'disabled active');

$('#store-tab').not('#store-tab.disabled').click(function(event){
    $('#store-tab').attr('class', 'active');
    $('#bank-tab').attr('class', '');
    return true;
});
$('#bank-tab').not('#bank-tab.disabled').click(function(event){
    $('#bank-tab').attr('class' ,'active');
    $('#store-tab').attr('class', '');
    return true;
});

$('#store-tab').click(function(event){return false;});
$('#bank-tab').click(function(event){return false;});

$('.selectKid').click(function(event){
    $('.checkbox').removeAttr("disabled");
    $('#bank-tab').attr('class', 'active');
    $('#store-tab').attr('class', '');
});
});
```

Comment: If you want disabled tabs with Next/Previous buttons, check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/20672122/563309

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the solution. It seems bootstrap doesn't like you changing the active tags manually.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#store-tab').attr('class', 'disabled');
    $('#bank-tab').attr('class', 'disabled active');

    $('#store-tab').click(function(event){
        if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    $('#bank-tab').click(function(event){
        if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    $('.selectKid').click(function(event){
        $('.checkbox').removeAttr("disabled");
        $('#bank-tab').attr('class', 'active');
        $('#store-tab').attr('class', '');
    });
});
```

Comment: I actually can't get any of the posted solutions to work for me on jsFiddle, but I'm glad you found something that works for you.

Comment: That is strange that it won't work on jsFiddle.. The code I am using for my project and on jsFiddle are identical with the exception of the content in the tabs...

Comment: Ha, there's a typo in your bootstrap.js include - `<script src="http://twitter.github.com /bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap.js">` (note the space)

Comment: @Sara That is weird! My code is working on my machine but not on the fiddle. Ah well, at least a solution was found!

Comment: @kyle.stearns the culprit is the space in the `bootstrap.js` include in the fiddle.

Comment: Doesn't work for me either. Even if I put a `console.log` function to show that the `disabled` class was detected, it still goes ahead to open the tab anyway.

Answer (score 9):

HTML: Just add class disabled

JQUERY:

```
$(".disabled").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#store-tab').click(function(event){
    if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) { return false; }
    $('#store-tab').attr('class', 'active');
    $('#bank-tab').attr('class', '');
    return true;
});
$('#bank-tab').click(function(event){
    if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) { return false; }
    $('#bank-tab').attr('class' ,'active');
    $('#store-tab').attr('class', '');
    return true;
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MRghr/)

I changed your `.not()` to an if statement, as I think it was causing your events to be bound incorrectly.
I also removed the two click events that just returned false as they seemed superfluous.

Comment: This makes the tabs clickable, however the content does not change. Which means the data toggle is not happening I suppose? Would returning true cause the problem? I tried removing the return true statement. It didn't change any effect.

Comment: I have isolated the problem to the lines which change the class attributes of #bank-tab and #store-tab. I don't understand how those are affecting the issue however. When those are commented out everything functions normally. I suppose it was interfering with bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this JavaScript instead and it should work! This is a bit more slim and doesn't have the unnecessary `click` functions that are already built-in to the Bootstrap JavaScript. It simply disables the tabs, and re-enables them when you click on the 'Activate' button.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.nav li').attr('class', 'disabled');
    $('#bank-tab').addClass('active');

    $('.selectKid').click(function(e){
        if ( $('.disabled').length > 0 ) {
           $('.disabled').removeClass('disabled');
           return false;
        }
    });

});
```

**Explanation:** When the document is loaded add a class of `disabled` to `.nav li` (disable tabs). Add a class of `active` to the `#bank-tab` element (for styling purposes). When you click the 'Activate Tabs' button, if there are any elements that match `ul.nav li.disabled` remove the disabled class (to re-enable the tabs).

Answer (score 1):

None of these worked for me. The classes were only visual elements, and returning false on click on certain tabs didn't override the existing function. Not to mention it's hard to turn the tab on & off based on input.

Here's what I came up with.. to enable another tab to send the user back to it.

```
$('#rentalstab_button').click(function(event){
    if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
        $('#detailstab_button').trigger('click');
        return false;
    }
});
```

The HTML on the tab triggers:

```
<li role="presentation"><a href="#basicinfotab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Basic Info</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="#detailstab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" id="detailstab_button">Details</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="#rentalstab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" id="rentalstab_button">Rental</a></li>
```

The Javscript that turns the tab button from disabled to enabled etc. is similar. In this code the `rentaldropdown` element is another `<select>` dropdown that dictates whether the tab should be enabled or disabled. Run this function attached as a `onchange` trigger.

```
if(rentaldropdown.val()==1) {
    // $( "#listing_form_tab" ).tabs("enable", 3);
    console.log('enabling rental');
    $('#rentalstab_button').prop( "disabled", false ).removeClass('disabled');

} else {
    console.log('disabling rental');
    $('#rentalstab_button').prop( "disabled", true ).addClass('disabled');;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ### Very Simple Way

```
.nav-tabs li.active a{
    pointer-events:none;
}
```