# javascript stop twitter bootstrap tab link from activating

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using TB 3 in my app. I'm using some nav tabs and I want to by default disable a few as follows (this is not part of a drop-down menu):

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="disabled"><a href="#tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab</a></li>
</ul>
```

My disable function:

```
$('.nav li.disabled').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

The goal is to remove `.disabled` when a condition is met so the link is re-enabled or clickable again. This changes the appearance of the tab only, not the functionality. Further tests show `shown.bs.tab` is still fired no matter what I do here.

Comment: likely simpler to just use tab styling and write own tab change code

Comment: Since the link is supposed to be inactive, why is its not responding to clicks a problem?

Comment: When the `.disabled` class is removed, I'd like the link to be clickable or re-enabled.

Comment: Hello? Did you check my updated answer?

Comment: I wasn't able to get it working. Instead I just hid the element with `display:none` until my object was ready in the DOM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, bootstrap doesn't "like" changing active tabs.

Here's the [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Saran/d5rRj/1/) (Bootstrap 3.0).
And the [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Saran/CZrzT/1/) (Bootstrap 2.3.2).
Here's the idea:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#store-tab').attr('class', 'disabled');
  $('#bank-tab').attr('class', 'disabled active');

  $('#store-tab').click(function(event) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
      return false;
    }
  });
  $('#bank-tab').click(function(event) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
      return false;
    }
  });

  $('.selectKid').click(function(event) {
    $('li').removeAttr("disabled");
    $('#bank-tab').attr('class', 'active');
    $('#store-tab').attr('class', '');
  });
});
```

[Courtesy of](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14486151/451962).

Comment: Works the same way with Bootstrap 2.3.2. I've listen new fiddle in my answer.