# Disable bootstrap tab clicks

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootsrap tabs for a  registration form ,
 I changed navigation of tabs using onclick event of next and previous button .
But still that tabs click works and being able to go the desired page easily Please help how can i stop tab click navigation i only want next previous button navigation 
Please find the html code below

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
   <li class="active">
     <a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">1.PERSONAL DETAILS</a> 
   </li>   
   <li>
     <a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab"> 2. CONTACT DETAILS</a> 
   </li>  
   <li>
     <a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab">3. EDUCATION DETAILS</a>
   </li>   
   <li>
     <a href="#course" data-toggle="tab">4. SELECT COURSE</a>
   </li>   
   <li>
     <a href="#settings" data-toggle="tab">5. PAYMENT DETAILS</a>
   </li> 
 </ul>
 <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">Form elements </div>
    <div id="profile">Form elements </div>
    <div id="messages">Form elements </div>
    <div id="settings">Form elements </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: create a fiddle that would be great. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: just remove data-toggle="tab"

Comment: refer below my clean and easiest solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you disable tabs in Bootstrap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237314/can-you-disable-tabs-in-bootstrap)

Answer (score 8):

I have tabs like this in the HTML (using Bootstrap 3.0):

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="createNotTab">
    <li class="active" ><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Step 1: Select Property</a></li>
    <li class="disabled"><a href="#createnotification" data-toggle="" >Step 2: Create Notification</a></li>
</ul>
```

Next/Previous buttons

```
<button class="btn btn-warning prevtab" type="button" onclick="return showPrev()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span>Previous </button>
 <button class="btn btn-info prevtab" type="button" onclick="return showNext()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span>Next </button>
```

In my JavaScript file:

```
 var $tabs = $('#createNotTab li');


function showPrev() {
    $tabs.filter('.active').prev('li').removeClass("disabled");
    $tabs.filter('.active').prev('li').find('a[data-toggle]').each(function () {
       $(this).attr("data-toggle", "tab");
    });

    $tabs.filter('.active').prev('li').find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').tab('show');

    $tabs.filter('.active').next('li').find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').each(function () {
        $(this).attr("data-toggle", "").parent('li').addClass("disabled");        
    })
}

function showNext() {
    $tabs.filter('.active').next('li').removeClass("disabled");
    $tabs.filter('.active').next('li').find('a[data-toggle]').each(function () {
        $(this).attr("data-toggle", "tab");
    });

    $tabs.filter('.active').next('li').find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').tab('show');

    $tabs.filter('.active').prev('li').find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').each(function () {
        $(this).attr("data-toggle", "").parent('li').addClass("disabled");;        
    })
}
```

If you are having multiple tabs, set `class="disabled"` and `data-toggle=""` for all the li items that you want to deactivate.

Answer (score 7):

I was having the same issue and this is what i used.

```
$("element").click(event) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
}
```

you just intercept the click event and then kill the event. To show the tabs, I'd just use $(tab.content).fadeIn();

Answer (score 6):

try this for disabling a tab

```
$('#tab').attr('class', 'disabled');

    $('tab').click(function(event){
        if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: even if it disables , i am being able to navigate using tabs
i want to stop navigation to next tabs through the tab click
it will happen only through next button click

Comment: try @Delphian suggestion

Comment: ya i tried that , then the next button also wont work
i mean after removing  data-toggle="tab" when you click the next button to go the the next tab it wont work

Comment: remove data-toggle="tab" and on click of next button show the target container and hide the other containers. On click of next, check which container to be navigated

Comment: yes i managed to write some jquery on onclick 
thanks for the idea

Answer (score 1):

**Super simple..**.

```
Add disabled class to tab li.

on show.bs.tab event attached to a[data-toggle='tab'] element 
check to see if its parent has the disabled class...

if so return false...
```

Comment: I like this approach, very clean.  It can be included in a js file across the application so that all that needs to be done is add the disabled class to the tab.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tabs > li").click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("disabled"))
            return false;
    });
});
```

It will be enough to work

Answer (score 1):

I used

```
style="pointer-events: none;"
```

something like:

```
<div class="steps nav" role="tablist">
    <div href="#first" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" class="step mb-4 active" style="pointer-events: none;">
        <div class="number">1</div>
        first
    </div>
    <div href="#second" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" class="step mb-4" style="pointer-events: none;">
        <div class="number">2</div>
        second
    </div>
</div>
```

seems to be doing the trick. still able to perform navigation using .click() function. which is what most are looking for.

something like

```
$('.nav [href="' + target + '"]').click()
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to disable the user Click on tab:

```
$('li:has([data-toggle="tab"])').click(function(event){return false;});
```

Maker sure this code will be added after your bootsrtap js

Answer (score 0):

I, had this problem for a while.

Remove the data-toggle = ..

to do conditionnaly by javascript
Give tabs, Ids in the  tag
document.getElementById(tabId)[0].setAttribute("data-toggle", "");

Answer (score -2):

I tried all suggested answers, but finally i made it work like this

```
if (AnyCondition) //your condition
{
    $("a[data-toggle='tab'").prop('disabled', true);
    $("a[data-toggle='tab'").each(function () {
        $(this).prop('data-href', $(this).attr('href')); // hold you original href
        $(this).attr('href', '#'); // clear href
    });                
    $("a[data-toggle='tab'").addClass('disabled-link');
}
else
{
    $("a[data-toggle='tab'").prop('disabled', false);
    $("a[data-toggle='tab'").each(function () {
        $(this).attr('href', $(this).prop('data-href')); // restore original href
    });
    $("a[data-toggle='tab'").removeClass('disabled-link');
}
// if you want to show extra messages that the tab is disabled for a reason
$("a[data-toggle='tab'").click(function(){
   alert('Tab is disabled for a reason');
});
```

Comment: Even though everyone downvoted this one, it actually is the best answer. It helped me to make this: $("#id" ).css( "color", "grey" ).prop('disabled', true);

Comment: @sol i don't know why the down voted it, it worked for me :)